# CMake dependency conflict with same header file names

Tags: c++, cmake

I am stuck in CMake dependency issue. CMake does not rebuild the program when I modified the CXX header files.

My file structure is as such

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── a.h
│   └── c.h
├── b
│   ├── b.h
│   └── c.h
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cxx
```

File contents:

a.h

```
$ cat a/a.h
#include "c.h"
```

b.h

```
$ cat b/b.h
#include "c.h"
```

main.cxx

```
$ cat main.cxx
#include "a/a.h"
#include "b/b.h"
int main()
{
}
```

CMake depend.internal

```
$ cat CMakeFiles/hello.dir/depend.internal
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.7

CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o
 /proj/mtk09331/work/tmp/cmake/a/a.h
 /proj/mtk09331/work/tmp/cmake/a/c.h
 /proj/mtk09331/work/tmp/cmake/b/b.h
 /proj/mtk09331/work/tmp/cmake/main.cxx
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(hello main.cxx)
```

As you can see, b/c.h does not exist in the dependency list.
Therefore, CMake won't rebuild the program if I modified b/c.h.

Does cmake not allow the same header file names?
Altough it works with renaming the header files.
But I would like to find a "correct" way to prevents this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide content of `CMakeLists.txt` too.

Comment: Already added. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need 2 different files with the same name?

Comment: Regardless of CMake, you have to specify the fullpath to the headers, either absolute paths, or relative to a registered include-path... You are just writing `#include "c.h"`, which is most likely relative to the directory of CMakeLists.txt, if you do not specify any `include_directories`. Change `#include "c.h"` to `#include "a/c.h"` and b/c.h respectively in a.h and b.h and both should appear.

Comment: There are two sub project developed by different teams. It is difficult for us to prevent header file name conflicts.

Comment: include_directories does not help for main.cxx to find include path.
Therefore, the only way to include c.h is #include "c.h" or " a/c.h".
But a and b are sub project which developed by different teams.
There is no way for sub project to know the root of all the root project.

Comment: Imho, this problem could be solved by organisational means only.

Comment: For example, it is common has a "config.h" in each sub project.
IMO, it is hard to prevent nested project with header name conflict in big organisation.

Comment: Hm.. I see whats the problem. But as @KonstantinL pointed out, you could solve this by organisational means. Or even handle the subprojects as real subprojects with individual CMakeLists.txt and proper deployment of each

Comment: add_executable(hello main.cxx a/c.h b/c.h)

Comment: @MABVT I have tried individual CMakeLists.txt but failed.
include_directories in sub project CMakeList.txt only affect sub project *.cxx, not main.cxx.

Comment: @RichardHodges I tried your suggestion but it takes no affect.

Answer (score 1):

As @MABVT notes in the comment, CMake is unrelated here: the question is about proper projects' organization.

From the point of projects' organization, headers for every project can be devided into two parts:

- **private headers**, which are used only for compile the project itself,
- **public headers**, which are used by the outer world (by other projects).

Naming and organization of *private headers* are fully up to the project's author.

But for scalable projects naming and organization of their **public headers** should follow several rules:

1. Name of the public header should be **unique** among *all projects*.

   Usually this is achived by moving these headers into the directory contained the name of the project.
2. Public header **shouldn't include** *private header*.
3. Public header should **include** other public header using only its *unique name*.

---

As you can see, headers `a/a.h` and `b/b.h` are **public** in your case.

But for headers `a/c.h` and `b/c.h` you should decide, whether they are *public* or *private*.

If you want to make `a/c.h` *private*, then *public* header `a/a.h` cannot include it (rule 2).

If you want to make `a/c.h` *public*, then public header `a/a.h` should include it using its **unique name**, that is `#include <a/c.h>` (rule 3).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a feature of **make**. As stated by @Tsyvarev, adding the sub-directory name in the `#include` statement helps **make** find the correct dependencies but looks awkward in the source code.

**ninja** correctly determines the dependencies in the case above. To use with **cmake** install **ninja** and select it with ...

```
cmake -G Ninja
```